# Android SDK Version at compile time

Tags: android, sdk, version, compile-time

There are a variety of variables stored in the `android.os.Build` class that you can check for the current version of the given Android platform.  Of course, these only work in an emulator or device as the SDK returns null or 0 during compilation

Is there any other variables available within the Android SDK that represents the current SDK version that is available during compilation via the Java API?

FYI, I am trying to implement this feature: https://github.com/johncarl81/transfuse/issues/18

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'available within the complier/Java VM' as on Android you are using the Davlik VM?

Comment: You compile Android Java code in the regular Java compiler first.  This generates Java Bytecode which is then turned into Dalvik Bytecode by the Android sdk.  I mean is there a version number available during the compilation phase when the Android Java is being turned into Java bytecode.

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding your question. I'm not aware of a major differences in bytecode between different Davik versions (or at least that matter to a App developer). Is there a reason why you want to know? Or am I missing your point.

Comment: I am looking for the version number in the Android Java API.  Build.Version.SDK_INT returns 0 in the Java API as it is just a stub in the API.  What I am trying to do is use the API version during compilation (see my feature reference).

Comment: Its a stub as it will only work in a valid environment, the code you reference is relatively standard in Android. See second answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551629/different-java-methods-for-different-api-levels

Comment: Right, and what I am trying to do is write a feature that implements this SDK switching feature at compile time, avoiding the need to switch at runtime with reflection.

Comment: The Lint documentation yields [this](http://tools.android.com/recent/lintapicheck) about API checks. I would try to use the `@TargetApi(...)` annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set a minimum SDK level, that can be done in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. If you want to support multiple SDK levels, you'll have to do that at runtime since its implied that you won't know if you are running at SDK 8 or SDK 15 until you are actually running your app. If you want to avoid lint warning, I would use `@TargetApi(...)` that opatut referenced......

Comment: So, here's the idea.  Since I can upload multiple support versions to the market, I can compile a different version for each API level.  If I can compile a different version for each API level then I can use different code or classes for each version I upload.  What I would like to do is leverage the API level in my custom Annotation processor library (compiler extension) to reference one component class or another based on the API level.  I bet I could set a variable in Maven, but I was wondering if there was a more build-system-agnostic way to do so.  Seems like the answer is probably no.

Comment: You would still need to do a runtime check to determine which OS level you are on since you don't know if the device got upgraded. Any build system/framework would need to take that into account.

Comment: You're right about that.  I hadn't considered upgrades.  I wonder if this feature would be still be handy with just a runtime if-statement.  Maybe I could generate this based on annotations. as described in the other question you pointed out.